# Write a program that asks the user to enter five test scores. Correspond it to a letter grade

Tags: python, function, for-loop

Determine_grade - accepts a single number as an argument and displays a letter grade for the score based on the following grading scale:

```
Score 90-100 80-89 70-79 60-69 Below 60

Letter Grade A
B
C
D
F
```

- calc_average - takes a list of grades as an argument and displays the average of the scores, along with a letter grade equivalent to that average.
- main - asks the user to enter five test scores and puts them as numbers into a list
- showLetters – echo prints scores entered by the user with letter grade equivalents

Write the comments by each major step. Here is a sample run of the program:

Enter the grades: 65,80,90,71,85

```
65.0 is D
80.0 is B
90.0 is A
71.0 is C
85.0 is B
```

The average is: 78.2 which is C

```
def main():
    enter code herescores = input("Enter five test scores seperated by commas:")
    listScores = scores.split(",")`enter code here`
    determine_grade(listScores)
    calc_average(listScores)

def determine_grade(grades):
    for num in grades:
        if int(num) >= 90 and int(num) <= 100:
            print("A")
        elif int(num) >=80 and int(num) <= 89:
            print("B")
        elif int(num) >=70 and int(num) <= 79:
            print("C")
        elif int(num) >=60 and int(num) <= 69:
            print("D")
        else:
            print("F")


def calc_average(grades):
    total = 0
    for num in grades:
        total += int(num)
    average = total / 5
    print(average)


#def show_letters(values):
main()
```

This is what I have so far but cannot seem to figure out how to format it?

Comment: Please ask this in the form of a question. Hint: whatever you ask should end with a `?`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This formats the output the way you want to format it:

```
def main():
    scores = input("Enter five test scores separated by commas: ")
    return [int(num) for num in scores.split(",")]


def determine_grade(num):
    if 90 <= num <= 100:
        letter_grade = "A"
    elif 80 <= num <= 89:
        letter_grade = "B"
    elif 70 <= num <= 79:
        letter_grade = "C"
    elif 60 <= num <= 69:
        letter_grade = "D"
    else:
        letter_grade = "F"
    return letter_grade


def calc_average(grades):
    average = sum(grades) / len(grades)
    grade = determine_grade(average)
    print("The average is: {:.1f} which is {}".format(average, grade))


def show_letters(num, letter_grade):
    print("{:.1f} is {}\n".format(num, letter_grade))


lst = main()
for n in lst:
    show_letters(n, determine_grade(n))
calc_average(lst)
```